# Is DETACH a clause or a some kind of modifier?

Tags: cypher, memgraphdb, opencypher

I'm trying to figure out the naming convention for parts of Cypher queries. [In Cypher Query Language Reference, Version 9](https://s3.amazonaws.com/artifacts.opencypher.org/openCypher9.pdf) `DETACH` is listed on page 197 as a clause.

But in all examples, I've seen `DETACH` used only in pairs with `DELETE`. So it is always `DETACH DELETE`.

```
MATCH (n)
DETACH DELETE n
```

or

```
MATCH (n {name: 'Andres'})
DETACH DELETE n
```

Does `DETACH` have any other purpose or can it be used only with `DELETE`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The terminology does seem to vary a bit here depending on what you read.

I have seen `DETACH` described as a keyword in some documentation and posts, but in the openCypher specification `DETACH` and `DETACH DELETE` are each classified as clauses in the table of available clauses.

Regardless, as far as openCypher goes, and as far as I am aware, Cypher too, `DETACH` is only ever used with `DELETE`.